# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "selection" of relation "users" does not exist LINE 1: UPDATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, routes

Currently getting error message:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "availability" of relation "users" does not exist LINE 1: UPDATE "users" SET "availability" = NULL WHERE "users"."id" ... ^ : UPDATE "users" SET "availability" = NULL WHERE "users"."id" IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "availabilities" ON "users"."id" = "availabilities"."user_id" WHERE "availabilities"."schedule_id" = $1)
```

Using a `has_many_through` relationship with models as follows:

User Model:

```
has_many :availabilities
has_many :schedules, through: :availabilities
```

Schedule Model:

```
has_many :availabilities
has_many :users, through: :availabilities
```

Availability Model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :schedule
```

I think my issue lies either in my routing or in my Controller action. I currently have the route the selection is being made on `schedules/:id/selection` which may be part of my problem?

routes.rb

```
resources :schedules do
  collection do
    put :selected
  end
  member do
    get :available, :unavailable, :selection
  end
end
```

schedules_controller.rb

```
#  Available to play method
  def available
    if logged_in?
      @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
      current_user.availabilities.create(schedule: @schedule)
      redirect_to @schedule
    end
  end

#  Unavailable to play method
  def unavailable
    if logged_in?
      @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
      @availability = Availability.find_by(schedule_id: @schedule.id, user_id: current_user.id)
      @availability.destroy
      redirect_to @schedule
    end
  end

def selection
  @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
  @users = @schedule.users
  @users.update_all(availability: params[:user_ids])
end
```

and the view:

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= form_for(:availability, url: available_schedule_path) do |f| %>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>

        <%= f.label :user_id, class: 'checkbox inline' do %>
        <%= f.check_box 'user_id[]', value: user.id %>
          <span><%= user.name %></span>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Set Lineup', class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Edit:

Added `available` and `unavailable` methods in the `schedules_controller`.

`available` method lets a user say they are Available for that Scheduled item. `unavailable` undoes this and destroys the record as I have no need to keep that information.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `@users.update_all(availability: params[:user_ids])`? Do you have a column `availability` in _users_ table?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `has_many :through` for a many-to-many relationship, you're essentially creating an array of foreign keys for each model; at least that's how Rails seems to treat it.

This `@users.update_all(availability: params[:user_ids])` should be:

`@users.update_all(schedule_ids: params[:schedule_ids])`

Each user has_many schedules. Each schedule has_many users. A schedule can be updated like:

```
@schedule.update(users_ids: params[:user_ids])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! `@schedule.update(users_ids: params[:user_ids])` deletes the entire record associated with the `schedule_id`. I am wanting to delete select records determined by a checkbox selection.

Comment: Frankly, that just shouldn't happen. Update does not call any destroy. Destroy must be called explicitly *or* you destroy one object that depends on it **and** you've set `dependent: :destroy` in the model. In other words, I don't know what you've done, but you're calling destroy on something at some point if the record is being deleted.

Comment: I am calling `destroy` in a controller action. Have updated the Schedules controller to include this and a short thing about what I think it's doing.

Comment: The other posters response is likely going to do what you want: `@schedule.availabilities.where(user_id: params[:user_ids]).destroy_all`

Answer (score 0):

update_all updates a field in the users Table. Availability is not a field but a relation (an array of rows from the availabilities table). 
If I understand right you want to remove the availabilities/users from the schedule, right? and you do that by selecting which users to remove? or un selecting them? 
if it is the firs option then what you probably want to do is this

```
def selection
  @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
  @schedule.availabilities.where(user_id: params[:user_ids]).destroy_all
end
```

if your options is the last then

```
def selection
  @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
  @schedule.availabilities.where.not(user_id: params[:user_ids]).destroy_all
end
```